# Have screen indicate there is a bell/alert with entire status bar

Tags: gnu-screen

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to have the entire status bar in screen change when there is a bell alert inside a screen session.

Internally at my company we use jabber, and being that I work in a screen environment 90% of the day I use a command-line based chat client. When someone in our company sends me a message I don't always see the alert right away. Right now it underlines the session name, but sometimes that is hard for me to notice.

For what it is worth, I am using mcabber for my chat client. I know you can run commands in addition to sending a bell alert for new messages - if that would help make this work.

Here is my current .screenrc

```
startup_message off

screen
screen -t jabber mcabber
screen -t root
screen -t misc

bind  ! select 11
bind  @ select 12
bind \# select 13
bind  $ select 14
bind  % select 15
bind \^ select 16
bind  & select 17
bind  * select 18
bind  ( select 19
bind  ) select 10

hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string '%{= kC}%{g}[%{G}%H%{g}]%{C}%?%-Lw%?%{Ck}%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?%{kC}%?%+Lw%?%= %{g}[%{B}%Y%m%d %{W}%c%{g}]'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass through the beep from background screens to the foreground session by adding `bell_msg "^G"` to your *.screenrc*, also you can add a custom message, example:

```
bell_msg "^GScreeno numero % is a hollerin'"
```

Adding the `^G` (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) can be done in *vi* / *vim* by first pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in insert mode, or in *emacs* by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

If you need to be notified of any activity on background screens you can add `monitor on` to your *.screenrc*, and customize the message with `activity "Something happened on screen %"`, adding `^G` here to ring the bell is also possible, but annoying.

---

If you are running it locally you can also simply set your chat client to use *aplay* to play an alert sound file, to distinct it from other beeps that could be less important.

If you run on a remote host you *could* make some reverse ssh portmapping to some custum service on the client side, and send sound through that, that would be over-course, but add a comment if you need such a solution.